# Loading custom installed PHP as default

Tags: php, macos, laravel, mcrypt, laravel-artisan

I've installed the latest version of PHP using [php-osx](http://php-osx.liip.ch) and it's working as expected on my apache web server. But the problem is when I try to run a `artisan` command in Laravel it asks for `mcrypt` module in order to run the command. Or when I try to install `Composer` via `homebrew` it asks for `openssl` module. Although both mcrypt and openssl are showing up enabled in `phpinfo()`. So my guess is that the php command in terminal is different from php that is loaded in apache. This is how my `/etc/paths` file looks like:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

And this is the output of `echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/local/memcached/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Is there a way to make the custom installed php, the default one used by terminal?

Comment: Usually `$PATH`environment variable supersedes /etc/paths, so do an `echo $PATH` and have a look at the order there

Comment: Thanks for the info @AxelAmthor, Edited the post with the output. But it seems that in my case it's not that different from the `paths` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can change that. But this could make some problems if you have some internal programms that use the installed PHP-Version. You can use the Mac-Port and install the missing packages.

```
sudo port install php5-openssl
```

https://www.macports.org/

Answer (score 0):

You would be better suited with Laravel Homestead, which already comes with everything you need to run Laravel in a Vagrant Box

```
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead
```